# BeautifulSoup --- if / else --- check if container contains another container then

Tags: python, html, selenium, if-statement, beautifulsoup

My problem refers to the last part of the code ###Bottom container:

Below website contains 17 "productlist-item__bottom-container" of which 4 contain a "productlist-item__discount-text"

https://www.nemlig.com/dagligvarer/husholdning/rengoering/opvaskemiddel/opvasketabs-pulver-til-maskine

What I would like to do:

for all container in "productlist-item__bottom-container"

```
if "productlist-item__bottom-container" contains "productlist-item__discount-text"
  store value in a list

else
  store value "no text" in the list
```

Thanks for your help.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

desired_width = 320
pd.set_option("display.width", desired_width)
pd.set_option("display.max_columns", 30)

chrome_path = r"C:\Users\Sebas\Desktop\chromedriver_win32 (1)\chromedriver.exe"

url = "https://www.nemlig.com/dagligvarer/husholdning/rengoering/opvaskemiddel/opvasketabs-pulver-til-maskine"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
browser.get(url)

import time
time.sleep(5)
html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

###Get the descriptions
all_descriptions = []
containers = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"productlist-item__info"})
for container in containers:
    brand = container.text

    all_descriptions.append(brand)

###Get the product name
all_productnames = []
productnames = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"productlist-item__name"})

for product in productnames:
    productname = product.text

    all_productnames.append(productname)

###Get the base price
all_basePrices = []
basePrices = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"pricecontainer__base-price"})
for price in basePrices:
    x = price.text
    all_basePrices.append(x)


###Get promo price
all_promoPrices = []
promoPrices = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"pricecontainer__campaign-price"})
for promoprice in promoPrices:
    promoprice_ = promoprice.text
    all_promoPrices.append(promoprice_)


###Bottom container

all_texts =[]

bottom_containers = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"productlist-item__bottom-container"})

for container in bottom_containers:
    discountText = bottom_containers.find_all("div", {"class": "productlist-item__discount-text"})

    if discountText != None :
        text = discountText.text
        all_texts.append(text)

    else :
        all_texts.append("No text")

print(all_texts) 


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Sebas/PycharmProjects/DePivotize/venv/Selenium.py", line 58, in <module>
    discountText = bottom_containers.find_all("div", {"class": "productlist-item__discount-text"})
  File "C:\Users\Sebas\PycharmProjects\DePivotize\venv\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1602, in __getattr__
    "ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?


  [1]: https://www.nemlig.com/dagligvarer/husholdning/rengoering/opvaskemiddel/opvasketabs-pulver-til-maskine
```

Comment: Hello, could you please make sure of the url because it's shown invalid here.

Comment: i think the correct one is https://www.nemlig.com/dagligvarer/husholdning/rengoering/opvaskemiddel/opvasketabs-pulver-til-maskine without `[1]`

Comment: Link corrected. Any idea where the mistake lays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what the `discount text` you are after, but is it possible that it's within the json response?

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


# Get coded timestamp for the api request url
url = 'https://www.nemlig.com/dagligvarer/husholdning/rengoering/opvaskemiddel/opvasketabs-pulver-til-maskine'

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Mobile Safari/537.36'}

s = requests.Session()
response = s.get(url,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
scripts = soup.find_all('script')
for script in scripts:
    if 'contentAsJson =' in script.text:
        jsonStr = script.text.strip().split('var contentAsJson = ')[-1][:-1]
        jsonData = json.loads(jsonStr)
        productStamp = jsonData['Settings']['ProductsImportedTimestamp']
        publishStamp = jsonData['Settings']['SitecorePublishedStamp']
        timeSlot = jsonData['Settings']['TimeslotUtc']
        deliveryZoneId = jsonData['Settings']['DeliveryZoneId']
        zipcode = jsonData['Settings']['ZipCode']
        productGroupId = jsonData['content'][0]['ProductGroupId']



# Access data from API
req_url = 'https://www.nemlig.com/webapi/%s-%s/%s/%s/%s/Products/GetByProductGroupId'   %(productStamp,publishStamp, timeSlot, deliveryZoneId,zipcode)
payload = {
'pageindex': '-1',
'pagesize': '-1',
'productGroupId': '%s' %(productGroupId)}


jsonData = s.get(req_url, headers=headers,params=payload).json()
products = jsonData['Products']
for each in products:
    if each['DiscountItem'] == True:
        try:
            print (each['CampaignAttribute'])
        except:
            pass
        print (each['Campaign'], '\n')
```

**Output:**

```
Fast mixtilbud
{'MinQuantity': 4, 'MaxQuantity': 0, 'TotalPrice': 90.0, 'CampaignPrice': 90.0, 'CampaignUnitPrice': None, 'Type': 'ProductCampaignBuyXForY', 'DiscountSavings': 29.8} 

{'MinQuantity': 3, 'MaxQuantity': 0, 'TotalPrice': 89.95, 'VariousPriceProductsCampaign': True, 'CampaignPrice': 89.95, 'CampaignUnitPrice': None, 'Type': 'ProductCampaignMixOffer', 'DiscountSavings': 47.9}
```

You can also get all that info into a table iterating through the json response:

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


s = requests.Session()

# Get coded timestamp for the api request url
url = 'https://www.nemlig.com/dagligvarer/husholdning/rengoering/opvaskemiddel/opvasketabs-pulver-til-maskine'

headers = {'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Mobile Safari/537.36'}


response = s.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
scripts = soup.find_all('script')
for script in scripts:
    if 'contentAsJson =' in script.text:
        jsonStr = script.text.strip().split('var contentAsJson = ')[-1][:-1]
        jsonData = json.loads(jsonStr)
        productStamp = jsonData['Settings']['ProductsImportedTimestamp']
        publishStamp = jsonData['Settings']['SitecorePublishedStamp']
        timeSlot = jsonData['Settings']['TimeslotUtc']
        deliveryZoneId = jsonData['Settings']['DeliveryZoneId']
        zipcode = jsonData['Settings']['ZipCode']
        productGroupId = jsonData['content'][0]['ProductGroupId']



# Access data from API
req_url = 'https://www.nemlig.com/webapi/%s-%s/%s/%s/%s/Products/GetByProductGroupId'   %(productStamp,publishStamp, timeSlot, deliveryZoneId,zipcode)
payload = {
'pageindex': '-1',
'pagesize': '-1',
'productGroupId': '%s' %(productGroupId)}


df = pd.DataFrame()
jsonData = s.get(req_url, headers=headers, params=payload).json()
products = jsonData['Products']
for each in products:
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame([each])
    df = df.append(temp_df, sort=True).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Output:**

```
print (df.to_string())
                                         Availability         Brand                                           Campaign CampaignAttribute      Category                             Description  DiscountItem       Id                                    Labels                          Name   Price                                       PrimaryImage ProductCategoryGroupName ProductCategoryGroupNumber    ProductMainGroupName ProductMainGroupNumber               ProductSubGroupName ProductSubGroupNumber  SaleBeforeLastSalesDate     Score      SearchDescription     TemplateName        UnitPrice  UnitPriceCalc UnitPriceLabel                                 Url
0   {'IsDeliveryAvailable': True, 'IsAvailableInSt...        Ecover                                               None               NaN  Maskinopvask                 25 stk. / zero / Ecover         False  5039333                             [Svanemærket]        Opvasketabs all in one   44.95  https://live.nemligstatic.com/scommerce/images...                   Opvask                 4800600000  Husholdning og dyremad             4800000000               Maskinopvask, tabs             4800600002                        0  3.433886          [OPVASKETABS]  productlistitem    1,80 kr./Stk.           1.80       kr./Stk.      opvasketabs-all-in-one-5039333
1   {'IsDeliveryAvailable': True, 'IsAvailableInSt...        Finish                                               None               NaN  Maskinopvask              60 stk. / Quantum / Finish         False  5038266                                        []           Maskinopvask (tabs)   99.95  https://live.nemligstatic.com/scommerce/images...                   Opvask                 4800600000  Husholdning og dyremad             4800000000               Maskinopvask, tabs             4800600002                        0  3.433886  [OPVASKETABS NEOPHOS]  productlistitem    1,67 kr./Stk.           1.67       kr./Stk.           maskinopvask-tabs-5038266
2   {'IsDeliveryAvailable': True, 'IsAvailableInSt...   First Price  {'MinQuantity': 4, 'MaxQuantity': 0, 'TotalPri...    Fast mixtilbud  Maskinopvask                   40 stk. / First Price          True   102160                                [Discount]             Maskinopvasketabs   29.95  https://live.nemligstatic.com/scommerce/images...                   Opvask                 4800600000  Husholdning og dyremad             4800000000               Maskinopvask, tabs             4800600002                        0  3.433886          [OPVASKETABS]  productlistitem    0,75 kr./Stk.           0.75       kr./Stk.            maskinopvasketabs-102160
3   {'IsDeliveryAvailable': True, 'IsAvailableInSt...  Grøn Balance  {'MinQuantity': 4, 'MaxQuantity': 0, 'TotalPri...    Fast mixtilbud  Maskinopvask                  30 stk. / Grøn Balance         False  5012162  [Den Blå Krans, Parfumefri, Svanemærket]  Maskinopvask alt-i-en (tabs)   32.95  https://live.nemligstatic.com/scommerce/images...                   Opvask                 4800600000  Husholdning og dyremad             4800000000               Maskinopvask, tabs             4800600002                        0  3.433886          [OPVASKETABS]  productlistitem    1,10 kr./Stk.           1.10       kr./Stk.  maskinopvask-alt-i-en-tabs-5012162
4   {'IsDeliveryAvailable': True, 'IsAvailableInSt...       Neophos                                               None               NaN  Maskinopvask                       2,50 kg / Neophos         False   101638                                        []         Maskinopvask (pulver)   79.95  https://live.nemligstatic.com/scommerce/images...                   Opvask                 4800600000  Husholdning og dyremad             4800000000  Maskinopvask, pulver og flydende            4800600005                        0  3.433886        [MASKINOPVASK ]  productlistitem    31,98 kr./Kg.          31.98        kr./Kg.          maskinopvask-pulver-101638
5   {'IsDeliveryAvailable': True, 'IsAvailableInSt...       Neophos                                               None               NaN  Maskinopvask                  0,65 l / Eco / Neophos         False  5008215                             [Svanemærket]    Maskinopvask 0% (flydende)   79.00  https://live.nemligstatic.com/scommerce/images...                   Opvask                 4800600000  Husholdning og dyremad             4800000000  Maskinopvask, pulver og flydende            4800600005                        0  3.433886        [MASKINOPVASK ]  productlistitem  121,54 kr./Ltr.         121.54       kr./Ltr.     maskinopvask-0-flydende-5008215
6   {'IsDeliveryAvailable': True, 'IsAvailableInSt...       Neophos  {'MinQuantity': 3, 'MaxQuantity': 0, 'TotalPri...               NaN  Maskinopvask                        1 stk. / Neophos          True  5009595                                [Discount]             Odour Stop 2-in-1   33.00  https://live.nemligstatic.com/scommerce/images...                   Opvask                 4800600000  Husholdning og dyremad             4800000000       Tilbehør til opvaskemaskine            4800600004                        0  3.433886          [LUGTFJERNER]  productlistitem   33,00 kr./Stk.          33.00       kr./Stk.           odour-stop-2-in-1-5009595
7   {'IsDeliveryAvailable': True, 'IsAvailableInSt...       Neophos  {'DiscountSavings': 79.95, 'MaxQuantity': 0, '...               NaN  Maskinopvask            70 stk. / All-in-1 / Neophos         False  5021615                                        []           Maskinopvask (tabs)  199.95  https://live.nemligstatic.com/scommerce/images...                   Opvask                 4800600000  Husholdning og dyremad             4800000000               Maskinopvask, tabs             4800600002                        0  3.433886          [OPVASKETABS]  productlistitem    2,86 kr./Stk.           2.86       kr./Stk.           maskinopvask-tabs-5021615
8   {'IsDeliveryAvailable': True, 'IsAvailableInSt...       Neophos  {'DiscountSavings': 20.0, 'MaxQuantity': 0, 'C...               NaN  Maskinopvask            25 stk. / All-in-1 / Neophos         False  5025942                                        []           Maskinopvask (tabs)   79.95  https://live.nemligstatic.com/scommerce/images...                   Opvask                 4800600000  Husholdning og dyremad             4800000000               Maskinopvask, tabs             4800600002                        0  3.433886          [OPVASKETABS]  productlistitem    2,96 kr./Stk.           2.96       kr./Stk.           maskinopvask-tabs-5025942
9   {'IsDeliveryAvailable': True, 'IsAvailableInSt...       Neophos                                               None               NaN  Maskinopvask   40 stk. / Classic Powerball / Neophos         False  5025945                                        []           Maskinopvask (tabs)   89.00  https://live.nemligstatic.com/scommerce/images...                   Opvask                 4800600000  Husholdning og dyremad             4800000000               Maskinopvask, tabs             4800600002                        0  3.433886          [OPVASKETABS]  productlistitem    2,23 kr./Stk.           2.22       kr./Stk.           maskinopvask-tabs-5025945
10  {'IsDeliveryAvailable': True, 'IsAvailableInSt...       Neophos  {'DiscountSavings': 50.0, 'MaxQuantity': 0, 'C...               NaN  Maskinopvask            50 stk. / All-in-1 / Neophos         False  5025966                                        []           Maskinopvask (tabs)  149.95  https://live.nemligstatic.com/scommerce/images...                   Opvask                 4800600000  Husholdning og dyremad             4800000000               Maskinopvask, tabs             4800600002                        0  3.433886          [OPVASKETABS]  productlistitem  149,95 kr./Stk.         149.95       kr./Stk.           maskinopvask-tabs-5025966
11  {'IsDeliveryAvailable': True, 'IsAvailableInSt...       Neophos                                               None               NaN  Maskinopvask               60 stk. / Neophos Quantum         False  5031592                                        []    Maskinopvaskemiddel (tabs)  163.95  https://live.nemligstatic.com/scommerce/images...                   Opvask                 4800600000  Husholdning og dyremad             4800000000               Maskinopvask, tabs             4800600002                        0  3.433886          [OPVASKETABS]  productlistitem    2,73 kr./Stk.           2.73       kr./Stk.    maskinopvaskemiddel-tabs-5031592
12  {'IsDeliveryAvailable': True, 'IsAvailableInSt...       Neophos  {'DiscountSavings': 20.0, 'MaxQuantity': 0, 'C...               NaN  Maskinopvask               22 stk. / Neophos Quantum         False  5031593                                        []    Maskinopvaskemiddel (tabs)   79.95  https://live.nemligstatic.com/scommerce/images...                   Opvask                 4800600000  Husholdning og dyremad             4800000000               Maskinopvask, tabs             4800600002                        0  3.433886          [OPVASKETABS]  productlistitem    3,63 kr./Stk.           3.63       kr./Stk.    maskinopvaskemiddel-tabs-5031593
13  {'IsDeliveryAvailable': True, 'IsAvailableInSt...       Neophos  {'DiscountSavings': 60.0, 'MaxQuantity': 0, 'C...               NaN  Maskinopvask               45 stk. / Neophos Quantum         False  5031594                                        []    Maskinopvaskemiddel (tabs)  149.95  https://live.nemligstatic.com/scommerce/images...                   Opvask                 4800600000  Husholdning og dyremad             4800000000               Maskinopvask, tabs             4800600002                        0  3.433886          [OPVASKETABS]  productlistitem    3,33 kr./Stk.           3.33       kr./Stk.    maskinopvaskemiddel-tabs-5031594
14  {'IsDeliveryAvailable': True, 'IsAvailableInSt...       Neophos                                               None               NaN  Maskinopvask                       65 stk. / Neophos         False  5042520                                        []               Maskinopvask 0%  179.95  https://live.nemligstatic.com/scommerce/images...                   Opvask                 4800600000  Husholdning og dyremad             4800000000               Maskinopvask, tabs             4800600002                        0  3.433886          [OPVASKETABS]  productlistitem    2,77 kr./Stk.           2.77       kr./Stk.              maskinopvask-0-5042520
15  {'IsDeliveryAvailable': True, 'IsAvailableInSt...       Neophos  {'DiscountSavings': 19.05, 'MaxQuantity': 0, '...    Fast mixtilbud  Maskinopvask  110 stk. / Classic Powerball / Neophos         False  5043729                                        []           Maskinopvask (tabs)  119.00  https://live.nemligstatic.com/scommerce/images...                   Opvask                 4800600000  Husholdning og dyremad             4800000000               Maskinopvask, tabs             4800600002                        0  3.433886          [OPVASKETABS]  productlistitem    1,08 kr./Stk.           1.08       kr./Stk.           maskinopvask-tabs-5043729
16  {'IsDeliveryAvailable': True, 'IsAvailableInSt...           Sun                                               None               NaN  Maskinopvask                           70 stk. / Sun         False  5028082                                        []           Maskinopvask (tabs)   79.95  https://live.nemligstatic.com/scommerce/images...                   Opvask                 4800600000  Husholdning og dyremad             4800000000               Maskinopvask, tabs             4800600002                        0  3.433886          [OPVASKETABS]  productlistitem    1,14 kr./Stk.           1.14       kr./Stk.           maskinopvask-tabs-5028082
```

Comment: Thanks, a lot for helping me out. I am after the orange text below the product picture: "4 stk. 90,- Kob flere. Best case scenario I would do it via beautiful soup, since I already started with it. I never worked with json etc. but I would happily look into it. I tried to find out where you got the link from. Could you please tell me? https://www.nemlig.com/webapi/4CbKt3-4-AGw6jr14/2019120509-60-600/1/0/Products/GetByProductGroupId?pageindex=-1&pagesize=-1&productGroupId=23a6edd6-7d28-4d27-bdc3-dd646fc80e53

Comment: If you go to dev tools (Ctrl-Shft-I) and look under the panel of Network -> XHR, you can find the call made to retrieve that data. Then in the window in that right panel, you'll see `Headers`, you can find the request url

Comment: Great, thanks. Found it. Tried to run your 2. code but I get an error: C:\Users\Sebas\PycharmProjects\DePivotize\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Sebas/PycharmProjects/DePivotize/venv/Nemlig_json.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Sebas/PycharmProjects/DePivotize/venv/Nemlig_json.py", line 8, in <module>
    products = jsonData['Products']
KeyError: 'Products'        Is there a problem with the link? When pasting in Chrome I get: "{"Message":"An error has occurred."}"

Comment: Ya, it looks like that request url is dynamic. For right now, you'd have to recopy and past the req url found in the dev tools. I'm trying to see how/where I can get the token that seems to change after a set amount of time

Comment: Ok figured it out. Its a coded time stamp. Give me a minute because I found it, just need to parse it.

Comment: @SebK ok updated it above. It requires you to go to the original site, which it then can get the required info to use for the api. So really, you don't need to look up that req api url, just use the url that you used for the browser in the first `url` variable

Comment: Perfect. Hopefully I will understand what you are about to do, to recreate myself

Comment: Just tried to run, but again does not seem to work: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Sebas/PycharmProjects/DePivotize/venv/Nemlig_json.py", line 36, in <module>
    products = jsonData['Products']
KeyError: 'Products'` Maybe my trial to do it with looping in BeautifulSoup might be the easier way? (Extra benefit for me: I would learn something. Your Json approach seems to be much more advanced which leaves me a bit lost :)

Comment: I just ran and it worked fine. You still using `https://www.nemlig.com/dagligvarer/husholdning/rengoering/opvaskemiddel/opvasketabs-pulver-til-maskine`? or is it a different url?

Comment: Weird. Copy & pasted exactly the code from your post: https://youtu.be/E010nGi4cyM

Comment: I opened the link https://www.nemlig.com/dagligvarer/husholdning/rengoering/opvaskemiddel/opvasketabs-pulver-til-maskine in the browser and ran your code again and it worked. Do you have useful website/video that gives me more info on how you built the timestamp? From what I understand you built it from elements that you find in "script". Would be great to learn it in a general way :). Thanks again for all the time you spent on this. Really appreciate it!!!

Comment: Ya that was tricky. I was just sort of looking around to see what changed in the url. And then trying to see if it was embedded abywhere. And then I did find it in the `script` tags, which is something I usually try when I can't seem to find the data by an api/XHR. There really is no site/video for building that timestamp... I've never really encountered that sort of timestamp thing before, it is pretty unique to this site/situation.

Comment: But, generally being able to pull `script` tags, and converting them to json formats that can get read into python is pretty useful. I honestly just learned it by trial and error, and just lots of practising/playing around.

Comment: Ok. So a lot of just try and error, as I somehow already assumed. Btw - Just tried to run the script again and it really does not work unless I manually open the browser and load the page...

Comment: ya, unfortunately. That's weird that it requires you to manually open it. I wonder if you include a `headers` in the requests if that would fix that? I updated it with a few extra lines. See if that works?

Comment: Not really - tried several different common user agents but did not work. Your header line is also missing quotations :) `headers = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36"}`

Comment: Ah good catch. Yup forgot those extra quote marks. Ya that’s a weird one. Never seen that before.